# Store locator vs SQL

Tags: sql, api, google-maps

I'm trying to build a store locator for gas stations with google maps api.
I've done everything as described here (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html), but

1. The search for address function does not recognize most of the input (I can live with that)
2. The SQL statement as provided by google does not return any results (I've checked that by substituting the statement with "`SELECT * FORM markers`", which works)

My DB table looks like

```
ID 
NAME
ADDRESS
LAT
LNG
```

and the statement I'm having troubles with is:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, address, lat, lng ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

which gets its values from the address search.

Does anybody have experience with this or a similar problem?

edit: found the first error: i missed out a comma between lng and (6371...
if I insert this directly in phpmyadmin (substituting '%s' with real values) i get the result i want, so I suppose the problem is passing the variables into SQL;
hope that helps narrowing it down.

Comment: echo $query onto the page and take a close look at it, paste it into you db management tool and check a) the computed query is valid and b) you have some matching results.

Comment: Are all those '%s' really supposed to be strings?

Comment: @Catcall: well that's my big problem. I don't know how to pass the variables (start point coordinates) from my index.php to the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in floats instead of strings, so your php should be

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name, address, lat, lng, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(%f) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(%f) ) + sin( radians(%f) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < %d ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: You inherited a missing comma from the original snippet, which was spotted by @richey. (The comma's been added now.)